# PHP Regex Negation For Youtube URLs

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

Let's say I have HTML in a database that looks like this:

```
Hello world!

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7t75u72vd">ABC</a>

Blah blah blah...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=df82vnx07s

Blah blah blah...
<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvs70fh17f3fg</p>
```

Now I want to use PHP regex to grab the 2nd and 3rd URLs, but ignore the first.

The regex equation I have so far is:

```
\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)
```

It works pretty well, but I don't know how to make it exclude/negate the first type of URL, one which starts with: href="

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Extract the text nodes with DOMDocument/DOMXPath first (avoiding links), then search each of them and create (eventually) new link nodes.

Comment: I would like to do everything in PHP using preg_match because the HTML is in a database and my code is already structured for it.

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML. http://php.net/DomDocument

Comment: OP may not be able to safely assume that the HTML is well-structured.  If not, using DomDocument is unsuitable since it would throw an error.

Comment: @Nate "The function parses the HTML contained in the string source. Unlike loading XML, HTML does not have to be well-formed to load...While malformed HTML should load successfully, this function may generate E_WARNING errors when it encounters bad markup." http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: @Nate I go under the assumption that 99% of people asking these questions are doing so because they look at the tools they know, before investigating new (and more appropriate) solutions, not because they're concerned about the cleanliness of their input.

Comment: One easy thing you can do is to run your text through `strip_tags()`. But I do strongly recommend learning how to properly parse HTML.

Comment: @miken32 I'm more accustomed to using DomDocument to work with XML, and was simply unaware that it behaved differently when parsing HTML.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "negative lookbehind" regular expression feature to accomplish what you're after.  I've modified the very beginning of your regex by adding `((?<!href=[\'"])http)` to implement one.  Hope it helps!

```
$regex    = '/((?<!href=[\'"])http)[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/';
$useCases = [
    1 => '<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7t75u72vd">ABC</a>',
    2 => "<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7t75u72vd'>ABC</a>",
    3 => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=df82vnx07s',
    4 => '<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvs70fh17f3fg</p>'
];
foreach ($useCases as $index => $useCase) {
    $matches = [];
    preg_match($regex, $useCase, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        echo 'The regex was matched in usecase #' . $index . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
// Echoes:
// The regex was matched in usecase #3
// The regex was matched in usecase #4
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add a `(?![^<]*>)` negative lookahead that will fail the match if the match is followed with 0+ chars other than `<` followed with `>`:

```
[a-zA-Z\/:.]*youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)(?![^<]*>)
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8RJTxI/1)

Note I also escaped `.` symbols to match literal dots, and used a non-capturing group with `be` part. You may replace `([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)` with `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` if you are not interested in the capture, and you also may replace `[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*` part with a more precise pattern, like `https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z.]*`.

Answer (score 0):

Example solution:

```
(?![^<]*>)[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)
```

[Visualization with an explanation](https://regex101.com/r/nM6liW/1)